# Java Event Handling : Significance of using this keyword in Event Listeners

Tags: java, awt, keylistener, windowlistener, mouse-listeners

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Appwindow extends Frame{
    String keymsg="This is a test";
    String mousemsg="";
    int mouseX=0, mouseY=0;
    public Appwindow()
    {
            addKeyListener(new MyKeyAdapter(this));
        addMouseListener(new MyMouseAdapter(this));
        addWindowListener(new MyWindowAdapter());
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawString(keymsg,10,40);
        g.drawString(mousemsg,mouseX,mouseY);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Appwindow ap = new Appwindow();
        ap.setSize(new Dimension(300,300));
        ap.setTitle("Application");
        ap.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class MyKeyAdapter extends KeyAdapter{
    Appwindow a;
    public MyKeyAdapter(Appwindow a)
    {
       this.a=a;
        }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
    {
    a.keymsg += e.getKeyChar();
    a.repaint(); 
   }
}

class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter{
Appwindow a;
public MyMouseAdapter(Appwindow a)
{
    this.a=a;
}
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
{
    a.mouseX=e.getX();
    a.mouseY=e.getY();
    a.mousemsg="Mouse down at" + a.mouseX+ "," + a.mouseY;
    a.repaint();
}
}

 class MyWindowAdapter extends WindowAdapter{
  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
 {
    System.exit(0);
}
}
```

this is a simple code to make a frame based window program. I just want to ask what is the significance of using this while registering an event listener...like in `addMouseListener(new MyMouseAdapter(this));`

Please explain to me what actually is happening in this line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Where ever you use that always `this`  references to the current object.

```
MyMouseAdapter(this));
```

That means  passing current `Appwindow`  to the  method

```
 public MyMouseAdapter(Appwindow a)
```

So that you can do some task in  `MyMouseAdapter` method on `Appwindow`

Answer (score 0):

You are telling the action listener to tell you when an event happens on an object (this) (your window). You key in for events sent by the mouse. It's like you are subscribing to a television channel. You say, "hey listener, when a mouse event happens on the window, tell me."  You'll be told in the interface method you have to implement for this listener

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a reference that is only available in an instance context. That is, it references the current object you are operating in. A `Frame` can register a number of listeners (`KeyListener`, `MouseListener`, etc.). Your custom class implementations want to have some reference to the `Frame` you are registering them on. One way to achieve that is by passing the reference to the current `Frame` (ie. `AppWindow`) object with `this` through the class' constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, you're registering a listener, that is, a class that implements a certain listener interface or, as in your case, inherits from a certain class (in your case `MouseAdapter`).

Because `MyMouseAdapter` *is* of type MouseAdapter, Java can count on it having a method `mousePressed(MouseEvent e)`.

That's the first half.

Now, it just so happens that your particular implementation of this mouse adapter wants to do something when the mouse it's pressed, and that something includes adding a message to your window, so, it needs to have access to that window (`AppWindow` to be precise). You *could* pass that on each call to `mousePressed`, but you don't get to define that interface. Instead, what you are doing is passing the AppWindow instance at the constructor of the MouseAdapter.

Now, it just so happens that you're doing this *from* the AppWindow, so, from your code's point of view, when you call `addMouseListener(new MyMouseAdapter(this));` this refers to the current object, i.e. the AppWindow

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but I was wondering about the same and came across this question. The answers provided did help me but did not provide me a complete picture.

I understood the concept from the following program on which I have put comments 
so that others with the same question can understand the concept more easily.

```
 public class MousePressedDemo extends Applet {

   public void init(){

  //question was why we are passing "this" in line below
  //at this point just understand like any use of "this" keyword 
  // it points to current
  //object of class MousePressedDemo or current applet window
  //we are passing it to the constuctor of MyMouseAdapter class

  addMouseListener(new MyMouseAdapter(this); // why we pass this in this line 

  }

 } // closing class MousePressedDemo 

 class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter{

 // line below creates ref var of class MousePressedDemo 
 //to which we can assign an object of type class MousePressedDemo

 MousePressedDemo mousePressedDemo;  

 //below constructor taking object of class MousePressedDemo as parameter.
 public MyMouseAdapter(MousePressedDemo mousePressedDemo){ 

  // the line below is the answer we are looking for. The object of class  
  // or applet window  We pass as "this" is now passed to a ref variable in  
  // this class. now using this reference var we can access the original 
  // applet window. look below to see how it is used to show message  
  // on status bar of original window

   this.mousePressedDemo = mousePressedDemo; 

}// closing constuctor


 public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me){

 // show message on status window of original applet class

mousePressedDemo.showStatus("MOuse Pressed");

 } // close method


} // closing class MyMouseAdapter
```